# Convert the html page to docx with css (designing) + rails

Tags: html, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, docx, doc

I want to convert an HTML page to docs page with all HTML design and css. So Its looks same like HTML page.  I'm using ruby 2.5.0. and Rails 5.2.0. If someone has the idea please share your suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The css styling you actually need might be a good place to start. CSS and word formatting are definitely not a 1 to 1 relationship so understanding what needs to be converted is very important to this question. However if just generating a docx is good enough and the html part is inconsequential then [`caracal`](https://github.com/trade-informatics/caracal) looks pretty extensive

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but caracal is not a rich library to fulfill my goal.I'm already using caracal.

Comment: Then you should probably make the question a bit more specific as to what your goals are, so that others can try and assist

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I will edit the question.